# Creating custom types for large constructions

Tags: c#

I have a method which return Tuple which contains two dictionaries

```
Tuple<Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty>, Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty>> GetDictionaries();
```

So I create two classes for this type.

```
public class PropertyDictionary : Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty>{}
```

and

```
public class PropertyDictionaryTuple : Tuple<PropertyDictionary, PropertyDictionary>
    {
        public PropertyDictionaryTuple(PropertyDictionary fromFluxData, PropertyDictionary localData)
            : base(fromFluxData, localData)
        {
        }
    }
```

But when I try do something like this:

```
PropertyDictionaryTuple data = GetDictionaries();
```

I have error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple,Syst‌​em.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'PropertyDictionaryTuple'

How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide the full error you get in your IDE. I assume it says "Cannot cast/convert X to Y", but now we have to guess.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,ICustomProperty>,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,ICustomProperty>>' to 'PropertyDictionaryTuple'

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `PropertyDictionaryTuple` is derived from `Tuple<PropertyDictionary, PropertyDictionary>` doesn't mean that every `Tuple<PropertyDictionary, PropertyDictionary>` is a `PropertyDictionaryTuple`.

`PropertyDictionaryTuple` isn't an alias for a specific `Tuple<PropertyDictionary, PropertyDictionary>` - it's a completely new type, which can have its own fields and methods etc.

In general, inheritance allows you to *lower* the generalization of types - you can assign a value of `string` to a variable of `object`, for example. It can't really work the other way around - if it were possible to cast any `object` to a `string`, well... how would that work?

If you want to convert the less specific type to a more specific type, you need to implement the conversion yourself. For example,

```
var dictionaries = GetDictionaries();
var pdt =
  new PropertyDictionaryTuple
  (
    new PropertyDictionary(dictionaries.Item1), 
    new PropertyDictionary(dictionaries.Item2)
  );
```

(you also need to implement the `PropertyDictionary` constructor that creates a copy of the original dictionary)

This will of course create a *new* `PropertyDictionaryTuple`, with two *new* dictionaries inside.

Or just change the `GetDictionaries` method to return (and create) a `PropertyDictionaryTuple` outright.

**EDIT:**

The `PropertyDictionary` definition could look something like this:

```
public class PropertyDictionary : Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty>
{
  public PropertyDictionary(Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty> dict)
    : base(dict)
  {}
}
```

Comment: PropertyDictionary constructor :
Something like this?
public PropertyDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty> Data = new Dictionary<string, ICustomProperty>();
         }

Comment: @VolodymyrGnatiuk Not at all. See my edit. You should probably read through some book on C#, those are the very basics of the language (and class-based OOP, really). Guessing your way around doesn't tend to end up well.